# Django when adding user as foreignkey get django.utils.functional.__proxy__ exception

Tags: django, exception, proxy, foreign-keys

I am trying to import newsletter subscription from an old mysql database into new django newsletter app, code looks like this:

```
for _ns in CmsModuleNmsList.objects.using('old').all():
            ns = Newsletter(pk=_ns.listid, title=_ns.name, slug=slugify(_ns.name), email='email@email.com', sender='Admin')
            ns.save()
            for _list in CmsModuleNmsListuser.objects.using('old').filter(listid=_ns.listid):
                try:
                    _user = CmsModuleNmsUsers.objects.using('old').get(userid=_list.userid)
                    user = None
                    try:
                        user = User.objects.get(email=_user.email)
                    except:
                        print "Cannot find user"
                    Subscription(newsletter=ns, user=user, subscribed=True, email_field=_user.email, name_field=_user.username, create_date=_user.dateadded).save()
                except Exception as e:
                    transaction.rollback()
                    print _user.username, 'Error', str(e)
```

When I run it, I get exceptions like this  which causes by this line `Subscription(newsletter=ns, user=user, subscribed=True, email_field=_user.email, name_field=_user.username, create_date=_user.dateadded).save()` and if I take out `user=user` I don't get the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after digging through the newsletter's code I found these lines were causing the issue:

```
assert ((self.user and not self.email_field) or
                (self.email_field and not self.user)), \
            _('If user is set, email must be null and vice versa.')
```

I was setting the user also setting the email...

Reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#translated-strings